# Function to format string in node.js

Tags: string, node.js

Is there something in node.js to format string like this:

```
format("HEY! my name is #{name} and I live at #{place}", {name: "joe", "place":"london"})
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript equivalent to printf/string.format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format)

Comment: This has been asked many times, many different ways. The answer is always: no, there's nothing built in but there are tons of libs for you to choose from: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=javascript+sprintf&safe=active

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, but if you use CoffeeScript you can use that syntax:

```
name = "joe"
place = "london"

console.log("HEY! my name is #{name} and i live at #{place}")
```